# Configuring extra interfaces in wildfly swarm

Tags: networking, wildfly, swarm, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to configure an extra interface in a wildfly swarm project.

The documentation says you just have to add the following snippets to the `project-defaults.yml` :

```
swarm:
  network:
   interfaces:
    backnet:
      bind: 192.168.4.5
```

But this doesn't work. Does anyone know if this is actually implemented?

I can add that setting the logging level to `TRACE` will output the generated `xml` configuration that shows only the default `public` interface and no `backnet` at all.

EDIT: I'm working with latest "stable" swarm : `2018.1.1`

Comment: I don't really know, but it seems you sometimes indent with 1 space and sometimes with 2 spaces. Not sure if the YAML format is fine with that. Maybe try to unify the indentation?

Comment: YAML indentation is definitively not a problem in my case.

Comment: If this isn't working, please raise an issue here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM so that we can investigate

Comment: Done : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-1813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a WA solution so far : add an `XML` snippets for interfaces:

I have to start the app like this:

```
java -Dswarm.local.ip=`hostname --ip-address` -jar myapp-swarm.jar -c config.xml
```

With this XML snippets (`config.xml`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:5.0">
  <interfaces>
    <interface name="mylocalif">
        <inet-address value="${swarm.local.ip}"/>
    </interface>
 </interfaces>
</server>
```

This will be merged with the rest of the `yaml` generated conf and work. I still would like to do everything with YAML though.